# How to create JAMROOT file to generate python .so file with cppObjConverter.cpp linked to C++ shared Libraries

Tags: python, c++, boost, shared-libraries, bjam

I have 3 shared libraries generate through c++
 1. **libfile1.so**
 2. **libfile2.so**
 3. **libfile2.so**

I have 2 external shared Libraries also
1. **gumbo-parser**
2. **libcurl**

I have two more files:
 1.  This file includes boost libraries
    ---> **cppObjConverter.cpp**
 2. This file calls cpp object to get data in python objects
    ---> **cppObjCaller.py**

I wanted to generate .so file **converter.so** linked with c++ shared libraries to import it in python.

Please suggest Jamroot file structure:
Sample file like below:

`import python ;`

`if ! [ python.configured ]`
`{`
   `ECHO "notice: no Python configured in user-config.jam" ;`
    `ECHO "notice: will use default configuration" ;`
    `using python ;`
`}`

`# Specify the path to the Boost project.  If you move this project,`
`# adjust this path to refer to the Boost root directory`
`use-project converter_project`
  `: ../../../.. ;`

`# Set up the project-wide requirements that everything uses the boost_python library from the project whose global ID is
 /boost/python.`
`project`
  `: requirements <library>/boost/python//boost_python 
                 <implicit-dependency>/boost//headers`
  `: usage-requirements <implicit-dependency>/boost//headers 
  ;`

`# Declare the three extension modules.  You can specify multiple source files after the colon separated by spaces.`
`python-extension converter :`   ``` cppObjConverter.cpp -L. -lfile1 -lfile1 -lfile1 -lboost_python ``pkg-config --cflags --libs gumbo`` -lcurl; ```
***`#I am not sure of above code line, I am expecting this as we do in c++ while generate object file linked to shared lib to generate common .so`***

`# Put the extension and Boost.Python DLL in the current directory, so that running script by hand works.`
`install convenient_copy`
  `: converter`
  `: <install-dependencies>on <install-type>SHARED_LIB <install-type>PYTHON_EXTENSION 
    <location>.`
  `;`

`# A little "rule" (function) to clean up the syntax of declaring tests  of these extension modules.`
`local rule run-test ( test-name : sources + )`
`{`
    `import testing ;` 
    `testing.make-test run-pyd : $(sources) : : $(test-name) ;` 
`}`

`# Declare test targets`
`run-test doctest : converter cppObjCaller.py ;`

Comment: No one has any source of answer to this question?